# MVC3 Razor jQuery autocomplete passes Back values but nothing displays

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having trouble with my auto complete functionality, it hits the controller and returns the values but nothing is displayed on the page, I have provided the code below any help is appreciated.

HomeControllerMethod

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult  GetAccounts(string id)
    {
        var accounts = NavRepository.GetAccountsBasedOnString(id);

        return Json(accounts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

About.cshtml

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#searchTerm').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "Home")',
                data: { id: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                minLength: 3,
                success: function (event, ui) {
                    searchTerm.valueOf (ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{               
<form method="post" action="">
 <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
     <input type="submit" value="Go" />
 </form>
}
```

Edit:
Below is my final function

```
  $(function () {
    $('#searchTerm').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "Home")',
                data: { id: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                minLength: 3,
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data); ;
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the JSON that the controller action returns look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to call the `response` function that the widget supplies to the `source` function you provide. Also, it looks like you have one of the autocomplete's options (`minLength`) mixed in with the AJAX call:

   ```
   $('#searchTerm').autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("GetAccounts", "Home")',
               data: { id: request.term },
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'POST',
               success: function (data) {
                   response(data); // You may have to perform post-processing here depending on your data.
               }
           });
       },
       minLength: 3
   });
   ```
2. Additionally, make sure that you're supplying the widget with the data it expects. You need to supply the `response` function with an array of strings, e.g:

   ```
   ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
   ```

   Alternatively, you can supply an array of objects with a *label* property, a *value* property, or both:

   ```
   [{ label: "Item1", value: "1" }, { label: "Item2", value: "2" }]
   ```

   You may already be doing this, but I would have to see what your controller action returns.

Comment: I changed this line and made it work thanks Andrew. success: function (data) {
                        response(data); ;